# Can i run a For Loop inside a GUI? As currently i am having problems with it therefore wanted to check it keep giving me IndexOutofBound

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

As I am not sure on how to do it as the for loop in the GUI doesn't seem to run and it keeps giving the exception there i am at wits end.

This is the code

```
public static class HelpWindow extends JDialog {

    JLabel label;

    public HelpWindow(JFrame frame) {
        super(frame, "Help", true);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        label = new JLabel("Hey you");
        add(label);
    }
}

public static class AddQnA extends JDialog {

    JLabel label, label2, label3, label4;
    JTextField question, answer;
    JButton input, reset;
    JTextArea textarea;

    ArrayList<String> ques = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> ans = new ArrayList<>();

    public AddQnA(JFrame frame) {
        super(frame, "Add Question & Answer", true);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        label = new JLabel("Question :");
        add(label);

        question = new JTextField(60);
        add(question);

        label2 = new JLabel("Answer   : ");
        add(label2);

        answer = new JTextField(60);
        add(answer);

        input = new JButton("Submit");
        add(input);

        reset = new JButton("Reset");
        add(reset);

        label3 = new JLabel("Please use the \"x\" on the top right to exit this section");
        add(label3);

        label4 = new JLabel("");
        add(label4);

        textarea = new JTextArea(10, 25);
        add(textarea);
        textarea.setEditable(false);

        Reset a = new Reset();
        reset.addActionListener(a);

        Submit b = new Submit();
        answer.addKeyListener(b);

        Submit c = new Submit();
        input.addActionListener(c);
    }

    public class Reset implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            question.setText("");
            answer.setText("");
        }
    }

    public class Submit implements KeyListener, ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // Not in use as of now therefore no method will be here
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent b) {
            int keycode = b.getKeyCode();
            if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                ques.add(question.getText());
                ans.add(answer.getText());
                label4.setText("**Question & Answer has been Added**");
                textarea.append("Question:" + question.getText() + "\n");
                textarea.append("Answer:" + answer.getText() + "\n\n");
                question.setText("");
                answer.setText("");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // Not in use as of now therefore no method will be here
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent c) {
            ques.add(question.getText());
            ans.add(answer.getText());
            label4.setText("**Question & Answer has been Added**");
       for (int i = 0; i < ques.size(); i++) {
            if (ques.get(i) == null) {
                textarea.append("There are no newly added questions or answers");
            } else {
                textarea.append("Question: " + ques.get(i));
                textarea.append("Answer: " + ans.get(i) + "\n");
            }
        }
            question.setText("");
            answer.setText("");
        }

    }
}

public static class DisplayQnA extends JDialog {

    JLabel label;
    JTextArea textarea;
    JMenuBar display;
    JMenu file;
    JMenuItem show;

    ArrayList<String> ques = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> ans = new ArrayList<>();

    public DisplayQnA(JFrame frame) {
        super(frame, "Display Question & Answer", true);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        label = new JLabel("Displaying All Questions And Asnwers");
        add(label);

        AddQnA qa;
        qa = new AddQnA(frame);
        textarea = new JTextArea(10, 25);
        add(textarea);
        textarea.setEditable(false);

       for (int i = 0; i < qa.ques.size(); i++) {
            if (qa.ques.get(i) == null) {
                textarea.append("There are no newly added questions or answers");
            } else {
                textarea.append("Question: " + qa.ques.get(i));
                textarea.append("Answer: " + qa.ans.get(i) + "\n");
            }
        }


    }
}
```

}

i am trying to get a input into my AddQnA arrays and than pull it from the DisplayQnA but it doesn't seemed to work at all. It just pops out a blank page, so i was also wondering is that as both Add and Display will pop up their own JFrames means when i cross Add JFrame will the information on the array stay or will it be deleted ?

Comment: Your IndexOutofBounds exception likely has nothing to do with the GUI, but regardless, for better help, please post a valid [mcve], code we can compile and run, and please show the full exception stacktrace, indicating which line causes it.

Comment: My guess is that it may be coming from this: `qa.ans.get(i)` since you know that the loop is not going beyond the `qa.ques` collection's bounds, but are not testing to see if it is going over the `qa.ans` collection's bounds. Test it!

Comment: Please see edit to answer

Answer (score 1):

`qa.ques` and `qa.ans` refer probably to distinct `List`s.
You loop over  `qa.ques` but you also refer to `qa.ans` during the loop:

```
 textarea.append("Answer: " + qa.ans.get(i) + "\n");
```

As the two `List`s refer very probably to two distinct objects, these may  not necessarily be populated on the same indexes of the `List`.
A better way would be using a single `List` parameterized with a custom class.
For example : `List<QuestionAndAnswers> questionAndAnswersList`.

You could then loop over :

```
for (QuestionAndAnswers questionAndAnswers : questionAndAnswersList) {
    if (questionAndAnswers  == null) {
        textarea.append("There are no newly added questions or answers");
    } else {
        textarea.append("Question: " + questionAndAnswers.getQuestion());
        textarea.append("Answer: " +  questionAndAnswers.getAnswer() + "\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got several problems with the posted code, but the biggest problem is the one I see here:

```
    public DisplayQnA(JFrame frame) {

        // .....

        AddQnA qa;
        qa = new AddQnA(frame); // ***** Here ****

        // ....

    }
```

I'm guessing that your code initially displays an AddQnA JDialog object, that you sue it to try to fill the question and answer ArrayLists, and that once the this dialog closes, you then display the DisplayQnA dialog. Within the DisplayQnA constructor you are creating an entirely **new** AddQnA object, one that is completely distinct from the one that (I believe) was previously displayed, and one that is never displayed and so has no chance to interact with the user. If my guess is correct (you don't show the code where you actually display these objects), then you have a problem of faulty assumptions of how Java and OOPs works. The key concept that you're missing is that objects of a class are completely distinct entities. Yes you change the state of a previously displayed AddQnA object (I think), but this has **no bearing on the state of the AddQnA object that you create within the DisplayQnA class**.

So, how to solve this? Or how do solve the issue of passing valid information from one object to another? There are several possible solutions:

1. You could make the ArrayLists within AddQnA `static` so that they are now fields of the class and not the object, and thus shared throughout the application. This solution is simple, direct, and completely misguided, since in doing this you throw out the OOPs baby with the bath water, and portions of your program loose the benefits of OOPs (object-oriented programming) structure, including reduced coupling, increased cohesion, improved testability,...
2. You could pass the information via setter methods or constructors. This could work.
3. Or best, but would require more work, you could try to extract out your program's "model" (the question/answer data) from its "view" (the GUI). This would lead to the most robust solution, one that would work best if the program scaled up to anything larger than a toy program, but may be overkill in an academic exercise.

So my recommendation is to go with solution 2 -- to pass the data where and when needed via setter methods.

Other issues: avoid using KeyListeners within text components. Much better to create a single ActionListener and add that to your JTextField since that will respond to pressing the enter key.

For example, you could display the data in a JList and pass the JList's model to both dialogs. This way the data entry dialog can enter the question and answer into the model, and the data display can display it (or both can display it if desired). For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AddDisplay {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            DefaultListModel<QuestionAnswer> qaModel = new DefaultListModel<>();

            // both share the same model
            EnterDataPanel entryPanel = new EnterDataPanel(qaModel);
            DisplayDataPanel displayPanel = new DisplayDataPanel(qaModel);

            JDialog enterDialog = new JDialog(null, "Enter Data", ModalityType.MODELESS);
            enterDialog.add(entryPanel);
            enterDialog.pack();
            enterDialog.setLocationByPlatform(true);

            JDialog displayDialog = new JDialog(null, "Display Data", ModalityType.MODELESS);
            displayDialog.add(displayPanel);
            displayDialog.pack();
            displayDialog.setLocationByPlatform(true);

            displayDialog.setVisible(true);
            enterDialog.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}

// class to encapsulate a single question/answer pair
class QuestionAnswer {
    private String question;
    private String answer;

    public QuestionAnswer(String question, String answer) {
        this.question = question;
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class EnterDataPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int COLS = 15;
    private JTextField questionField = new JTextField(COLS);
    private JTextField answerField = new JTextField(COLS);
    private DefaultListModel<QuestionAnswer> qaModel;
    private SubmitAction submitAction = new SubmitAction();

    public EnterDataPanel(DefaultListModel<QuestionAnswer> qaModel) {
        questionField.addActionListener(submitAction);
        answerField.addActionListener(submitAction);

        this.qaModel = qaModel;
        add(new JLabel("Question:"));
        add(questionField);
        add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
        add(new JLabel("Answer:"));
        add(answerField);
        add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
        add(new JButton(submitAction));
    }

    // abstract action is like an actionlistener "on steroids"
    private class SubmitAction extends AbstractAction {
        public SubmitAction() {
            super("Submit");
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_S);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // get text from text fields
            String question = questionField.getText().trim();
            String answer = answerField.getText().trim();
            if (question.isEmpty() || answer.isEmpty()) {
                // TODO:
                // if either text field is empty, show an error message
            } else {
                // both text fields hold text
                // create a QuestionAnswer object with it
                QuestionAnswer qa = new QuestionAnswer(question, answer);

                // add into our model and reset fields
                qaModel.addElement(qa);  
                questionField.setText("");
                answerField.setText("");
            }
            questionField.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DisplayDataPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int ROW_COUNT = 10;
    // jlist to display the data
    private JList<QuestionAnswer> qajList = new JList<>();

    public DisplayDataPanel(ListModel<QuestionAnswer> qaModel) {
        qajList.setModel(qaModel);
        // set jlist renderer to allow multi-line display
        qajList.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());

        // give a protoptype cell value so jlist is wide enough
        qajList.setPrototypeCellValue(new QuestionAnswer(
                "question question question question question question ", 
                "answer   answer   answer   answer   answer   answer   "));
        qajList.setVisibleRowCount(ROW_COUNT);
        JScrollPane qaScroll = new JScrollPane(qajList);
        qaScroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(qaScroll);
    }

    // cell renderer to display multiple lines of text in JList
    private class MyCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index,
                boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            if (value == null) {
                value = "";
            } else {
                QuestionAnswer qa = (QuestionAnswer)value;
                String q = "Q: " + qa.getQuestion();
                String a = "A: " + qa.getAnswer();

                // use simple HTML formatting to allow multiple lines
                value = String.format("<html>%s<br/>%s<html>", q, a);                        
            }            

            Component superComp = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            return superComp;
        }        
    }
}
```